# Schematic Question

Tags: oscillator, schematics, circuit-design

Where are the inputs and outputs in this schematic? Are there one or two?

[image]

Comment: IT LITERALLY SAYS IT IN THE SCHEMATIC DIAGRAM...

Answer (score 3):

It's an oscillator: no input.  Vout is the output.

Comment: What is the 9v for then?

Comment: The 9V is the power supply - I don't usually think of the power supply as an input to an amplifier or oscillator.

Comment: @PeterBennett ok so the 9v power supply would be the positive terminal of a 9v battery for example

Comment: Yes - and the negative terminal of the 9 volt battery would connect to "GND" in the drawing.